# Como modificar um arquivo JSON com o Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Estou usando o Mapbox. Quando se clica num poligono aparece o nome da pessoa que mora na cidade. Mas quero que quando eu clique mude o nome da pessoa no arquivo JSON.

```
map.on('click', function(e) {

var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
            layers: ['counties']
        });

var feature = features[0];


          $.getJSON('features.geojson', function(data) {

              feature.properties.nome = "JUBILEU";

         });

$('#QuestaoModal').modal('show');


});
```

Porem da errado dessa forma, não esta funcionando

Comment: Esse arquivo JSON é um ficheiro no servidor? é isso que queres mudar?

Comment: Na verdade ele esta na mesma pasta do projeto php/html que roda num servidor local (na minha maquina), wamp server

Comment: E eu quero mudar o objeto, dar um outro nome a ele etc

Comment: isso tem uma parte de lógica no servidor e outra no browser. Sabes como resolver alguma delas?

Comment: Não sei como resolver :/